# Adding a new USB port inside a Macbook Pro

Tags: usb, macbook

I have an USB Dongle that I'd like to put *inside* my Macbook Pro.  I have already found a spot that will fit the dongle.  The next question is splicing one of the USB ports and connecting it to the dongle.

Here's a photograph of the inside of my Macbook Pro, showing the USB ports and a little gray plastic divider with four holes in it above each port.

[image]

My question:

Does anyone know what is inside these holes?  Presumably each one is a pin for the USB port, right?  Can I just stick a wire in there, giving me 4 pins, plus the fifth attached to the metal outside the port?

More generally, any one have any ideas for what might be the easiest way to get a USB port inside my MBP? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just behind the connector indicated there are 4 small solder pads - 3 round and 1 square - these are the same on all the USB ports and I believe this is where the port is connected to the motherboard.

If you're very very very very good with a soldering iron you would be best off soldering 4 fine wires to these points and routing them to your internal USB device.

Note that the socket will become unusable, so blocking it off would be good - or even better, removing it altogether.  This would make soldering the wires in easier.

Not an easy job to do and the slightest slip could kill your MBP.

Comment: Great, thank you.  Question - why would the socket become unusable?  Would it be possible to put a "hub" in there somehow so that everything still worked?

Comment: To do that you would have to disconnect the socket from the motherboard and connect it directly to the hub.  You can only connect one device at a time to a USB port, so any wires connected to the USB port on the inside would constitute that port's device.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's been a while since anyone's added to this. I've been recently looking to add internal USBs as well and thought I am looking for the Macbook (not Pro) I assume there are some similarities. Among this website, I also stumbled upon another that gave more details about this port you are describing. In it they say the rear USB port (closest to the screen) already has a USB hub connected to it powering the IR, camera, trackpad, and keyboard.

Knowing this, I would take away two things; 1. don't bog down that port with more stuff, and 2. the other ports MAY have the capability of running a hub. Here's the site that I learned this from: http://blog.glo-networks.com/2010/08/10/macbook-pro-users-beware-the-phantom-usb-hub/